# Dirac spinor mass parameter

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, field-theory, fermions

Is the mass for a fermion simply obtained by taking $\partial_\bar{\psi}\partial_\psi\mathcal{L}\big\vert_{\bar{\psi}=\psi=0}$? So for instance, for $\mathcal{L} \supset m \bar{\psi}\psi + ig\phi\bar{\psi}\gamma^5\psi$, is the field-dependent mass $m I_{4\times4} + ig\phi\gamma^5$, with thus a squared mass equal to $\vert m I_{4\times4} + ig\phi\gamma^5\vert^2 = m^2 + g^2\phi^2$?